# How to read Azure app config values from Java SpringBoot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-app-configuration

I have a Springboot app that is trying to connect and read values from an app config resource.

Some keys in the Azure app config (which I am unable to change) are in this format

`

```
/application/config.datasource.jdbc-url

/application/config.datasource.password

/application/config.datasource.username`
```

I have a config Java class with prefix ("config"), but I don't know what member variables I should have in order to access "datasource.jdbc-url", "datasource.password" etc.

If the app config was just `/application/config.username`

then I could just use the below in my Java class

`String username;`

but for some of the configs that include multiple dots and some dashes (which Java identifiers can't have), how can I read the values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options depending on what you are looking for. You can either use `@Value("config.datasource.jdbc-url")` or you can use nested properties.

```java
public  class  Datasource {

  private String username;
        
  private String password;
        
  private String jdbcurl;

  ...
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
class MyProperties {

  private Datasource datasource = new Datasource();

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is similar to this sample [azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config-sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/appconfiguration/azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config/azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config-sample), please try to define the [properties class](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/blob/4ba43ef615e295c01fba0359402c696e7f412049/appconfiguration/azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config/azure-spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config-sample/src/main/java/example/MessageProperties.java#L13) to bind the configurations in Azure App Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Moarchy Chan`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.datasource")`

In `Azure portal`>`App configuration`> `Configuration explorer`, I have created keys and values for Username, Password and Jdbc url.

[image]
This is my Class UserProperties,

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.datasource")
        public  class  UserProperties {
        
        private String username;
        
        private String password;
        
        private String jdbcurl;
        
        public String getUsername() {
        
        return  username;
        
        }
        
        public  void setUsername(String username) {
        
        this.username = username;
        
        }
        
        public String getPassword() {
        
        return  password;
        
        }
        
        public  void setPassword(String password) {
        
        this.password = password;
        
        }
        
        public String getJdbcurl() {
        
        return  jdbcurl;
        
        }
        
        public  void setJdbcurl(String jdbcurl) {
        
        this.jdbcurl = jdbcurl;
        
        }
        
        }
```

Here is the UserController I have created,

```
     public  class UserController {

private  final UserProperties properties;

public  UserController(UserProperties properties) {

this.properties = properties;

}

@GetMapping("/Anu")

public String getUsername() {

return  "username: " + properties.getUsername();

}

@GetMapping("/vyshu")

public String getPassword() {

return  "password: " + properties.getPassword();

}

@GetMapping("/priya")

public String getJdbcurl() {

return  "jdbcurl: " + properties.getJdbcurl();

}

}
```

This the bootstrap for my code, you should add your connection string in {},
`spring.cloud.azure.appconfiguration.stores[0].connection-string= ${APP_CONFIGURATION_CONNECTION_STRING`}

This is the output for my Username,
[image]
This is the output for my Password,
[image]
This is the output for my jdbcurl,
[image]